# How to show current Ringtone title for Alarm, Notification, VoiceCall,

Tags: android, get, show, ringtone

I use this code, which I find more or less over here, but this return always same answer:
"Default ringtone is Gleam", which is not.

I would like to show users what sounds are set for:
alarm, system notification, voicecall, calendar notification, sms notification (did I forgot some?)

I tried to use this code:

```
SharedPreferences prefsRingtones =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(prefsRingtones.getString("RingtonePref","DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI"));
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
String ringToneName = ringtone.getTitle(this);
```

Or intead DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI use DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI, DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI

Answer (score 2):

thank you, it is working. For all other this is working code:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
String ringToneName = ringtone.getTitle(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the default value of prefsRingtones to RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION) instead of "DEFAULT_RINGTONE".

```
SharedPreferences prefsRingtones =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
Uri ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(prefsRingtones.getString("RingtonePref",RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)));
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
String ringToneName = ringtone.getTitle(this);
```

Change TYPE_NOTIFICATION to which ever sound type you need.

Comment: Also note that there are special cases for Silent ringtones you'll have to handle (ringtoneUri will be empty)